# How do I send an alert in front of a popover?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui, alert, popover

I am writing a Menu Bar app with just a popover which is where the action is. The target is MacOS 10.15 Catalina.

In the popover, I want to show an alert. The code is something like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var confirm = false
    var body: some View {
        return VStack {
            Button("Reset Settings", action: {
                self.confirm = true
            })
            .alert(isPresented: $confirm) {
                Alert(
                    title: Text("Do you really want to?"),
                    message: Text("Do you want to talk about it?"),
                    primaryButton: .default(Text("Oh, yeah")) {
                        print("Well, if you insist …")
                    },
                    secondaryButton: .cancel()
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The alert works well enough, but it appears *behind* the popover.

How can I put the alert in front of the popover?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the alert is declared on the view that the popover will be shown on top of (i can't see the popover in your code, so i can't be sure). If thats the case, then you'll need to declare your alert in the popover itself, not the view behind it.

**Example:**

```
var body: some View {
    VStack {
        Button("Reset Settings", action: {
                self.confirm = true
            })
            .popover(isPresented: $popoverPresentation) {
                
                PopoverView()
                    .alert() // declare alert here, inside the popover,
                // or even inside the `PopoverView`
                
            }
            // .alert() dont declare your alert here, outside the popover
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I don’t follow that. The view is indeed declared in the view, but that’s how all the tutorials do it. How would I declare the view in the popover, not in the view?

Comment: Updated with a better example. this same problem has happened to me too, but i'm still not 100% sure that your problem is the same as mine (although i think so).

Comment: I’ve never heard of PopoverView. Neither has XCode, as I’m getting the message `Cannot find 'PopoverView' in scope`.

Comment: O,PopoverView was just an example View. by PopoverView, i mean anything you consider putting in your popover. it might be a Text, might be a VStack with somethings in it, might be just a button, or anything else you wish, it depends on you.

Comment: Thanks. I tried your suggestion with a `Text`, but the alert still appears behind the popover.